# Flip Card with Greensock Tween and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tween, gsap

i've found a pen:

http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/vjGxH

**html**

```
<div id="mainWrap">
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="mainWrap" style="margin-top:10px;">
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack playcardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront playcardFront"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack playcardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront playcardFront"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardCont">
  <div class="cardBack playcardBack"></div>
  <div class="cardFront playcardFront"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body
{
  background:#444;
}
.cardCont
{
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  position:relative;
  /*border:solid 2px #fff;*/
}
.cardFront, .cardBack
{
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  background:url('http://s.cdpn.io/33073/lorempixel.jpg');
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cardBack
{
  background:url('http://s.cdpn.io/33073/lorempixe1l.jpg');
}

.playcardFront
{
  background:url("http://unlimitedpotentialnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Bouquet-cs.jpg");
}
.playcardBack
{  background:url("http://i203.photobucket.com/albums/aa158/Comic1111/ACe.png");
}
```

**js**

```
CSSPlugin.defaultTransformPerspective = 1000;

//we set the backface 
TweenMax.set($(".cardBack"), {rotationY:-180});

$.each($(".cardCont"), function(i,element) {

    var frontCard = $(this).children(".cardFront"),
      backCard = $(this).children(".cardBack"),
      tl = new TimelineMax({paused:true});

    tl
        .to(frontCard, 1, {rotationY:180})
        .to(backCard, 1, {rotationY:0},0)
        .to(element, .5, {z:50},0)
        .to(element, .5, {z:0},.5);

    element.animation = tl;

});

$(".cardCont").hover(elOver, elOut);

function elOver() {
    this.animation.play();
}

function elOut() {
    this.animation.reverse();
}
```

that displays a nice effect with greensock.
The problem is that is not cross-browser beacuse it doesn't work on safari.

Could someone help me to understand why?

Thanks

Comment: what happens on safari? Does the console say anything?

Comment: if you see the example in ff or chrome it works well (the card flip and shows the back), in safari the back is not shown after flip. The console doens't show errors...